Vertical scrollable content inside vertical carousel in React Native
I am trying to achieve a functionality where I put some vertical scrollable text inside a vertical carousel (react-native-reanimated-carousel). It should scroll the text first and when it reaches the end of the text then it should scroll the carousel to the next page in the same motion.
I have tried many methods but every time I had to lift my finger and again tap and scroll to trigger the carousel
Is there a way I could achieve all of this in a single motion without any janks?
const StackCards = ({ data }: { data: Post[] }) => {
  const headerHeight = StatusBar.currentHeight ?? 0;
  const window = Dimensions.get('window');
  const PAGE_WIDTH = window.width;
  const PAGE_HEIGHT = window.height - headerHeight;
  const [isVertical, setIsVertical] = React.useState(true);
  const [isCarEnabled, setIsCarEnabled] = React.useState(false);
  const carRef = React.useRef < ICarouselInstance > null;

  const handleScrollEnd = (nativeEvent: NativeScrollEvent) => {
    const contentOffsetY = nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
    const contentHeight = nativeEvent.contentSize.height;
    const layoutHeight = nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.height;
    console.log(contentOffsetY);
    if (contentOffsetY + layoutHeight >= contentHeight) {
      // Scrolled to the bottom, trigger next carousel item
      console.log('end');
      setIsCarEnabled(true);
    } else if (contentOffsetY <= 0) {
      console.log('start');
      setIsCarEnabled(true);
    } else {
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ height: PAGE_HEIGHT - 50 }}>
      <Carousel
        ref={carRef}
        enabled={isCarEnabled}
        onScrollEnd={(i) => {
          setIsCarEnabled(false);
        }}
        loop
        style={{
          width: PAGE_WIDTH,
          height: PAGE_HEIGHT - 50,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}
        vertical={isVertical}
        width={PAGE_WIDTH}
        height={PAGE_HEIGHT - 50}
        data={[...data]}
        renderItem={({ index, animationValue }) => (
          <Item
            key={index}
            post={data[index]}
            animationValue={animationValue}
            onScroll={handleScrollEnd}
          />
        )}
        customAnimation={animationStyle}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

